# How kafka routes the message to instance

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

As I understood kafka, number of partitions automatically assigned to number of instances of the application.
Ex: instance-1 assigned to partition-1
instance-2 assigned to partition-2
instance-3 assigned to partition-3

Let there is a gateway service having 3 instances which is listening to 'gateway' topic having 3 partitions.
If gateway is receive a request on instance-1, which is producing a message in 'user' topic which is listened by 'auth' service. Now auth service process the msg & produce message in "gateway" topic for partition-2.

My doubt is now how the instance-1 will resolve the request as it's assigned for partition-1.

Or we have to track from which partition message is received in the same partition msg has to be published?

My services are based on node.js

Answer (score 0):

> number of partitions automatically assigned to number of instances of the application.

False.

Counter example - Multiple instances of the producer are running and each sends records with the same key (value is irrelevant for the example). All records only arrive in one partition. Therefore only one consumer will be able to read any data from the multi-partition topic

Consumers instances can do manual partition assignment, but it is not "automatic" based on a particular number